# How to update a related model in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Here the scenario is, I have 3 models/tables: 
 1. `Teacher`
 2. `Course`
 3. `Course Assign to Teacher`

In the `Teacher` model/table there are two columns named: `credit_taken` and `remaining_credit` (`default 0`) and in the `Course` model/table there is a `course_credit` column.

So here is the problem: in the model/table `Course Assign to Teacher` when a `Teacher` takes a `Course` the value of this column should be calculated like this:
    remaining_credit = credit_taken - course_credit

I have implemented this, however instead of the value updating in database it's creating a new row in the `Teachers` table.

Here is my controller:

```
public function postcourseAssignTeacher(Request $request)
{
    $assignTeacher = new AssignTeacher();
    $assignTeacher->teacher_id = $request->Input(['teacher_id']);

    $teacher->credit_taken = $request->Input(['credit_taken']);
    $teacher->remaining_credit = $request->Input('remaining_credit');

    $assignTeacher->course_id = $request->input('course_id');

    $course->name = $request->Input('name');
    $course->credit = $request->Input('credit');

    $teacher->remaining_credit = $teacher->credit_taken -$course->credit;

    $assignTeacher->save();
    //    $course->save();

    $teacher->update();

    return redirect('courseAssignTeacherPage');
}
```

How do I update above two columns in teacher table instead of inserting a new record.

Comment: On reviewing this question about 3 times I don't understand your database structure. Please review and edit your question with a focus on consistency in naming your models and tables. You say in your question you have a new `Teacher` record created through your code, but in your code you create a new object called `AssignTeacher` which sounds like your other model `Course Assign to Teacher`. VERY CONFUSING! Please help us help you.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how your code even works as you're calling methods on a `$teacher` and `$course` variable that aren't even declared!?

Comment: See here 3 tables with 3 models. Teacher table has columns like `credit_taken` ,`remaining_credit` and course table has `course_name`, `course credit` and Im using another table `Course Assign To Teacher` and here Im keeping courses_id of courses table and teacher_id of teacher's table. In view page I'm taking this data, That's why Im creating new object like `Course Assign to Teacher` to save the data.

Comment: You call the model `Course Assign To Teacher` in your question then in your code you call it `AssignTeacher` it's really confusing! What you should be doing is using Eloquent's relationships to add a related record: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this:

```
public function postcourseAssignTeacher(Request $request)
{
    $assignTeacher = new AssignTeacher();
    $assignTeacher->teacher_id = $request->Input(['teacher_id']);


$teacher=Teacher::find(Input($request->['teacher_id']);


 $teacher->credit_taken = $request->Input(['credit_taken']);
    $teacher->remaining_credit = $request->Input('remaining_credit');

    $assignTeacher->course_id = $request->input('course_id');

    $course->name = $request->Input('name');
    $course->credit = $request->Input('credit');

    $teacher->remaining_credit = $teacher->credit_taken -$course->credit;

    $assignTeacher->save();
    //    $course->save();

    $teacher->update();

    return redirect('courseAssignTeacherPage');
}
```

and if you want to insert course should be create $course=new Course();