# I want to insert update the content of table when inserting from another table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel code that i used to insert data into a table, but i want to update the content of another table based on the details of the item inserted; below is my controller code

```
public function docadd(Request $request){


        $doc=new documents();
         $doc->claim_id=request('id');
         $doc->file_name=request('new');
         $doc->cat=request('new');
         $doc->type='needed';
         $doc->description='needed';
        $doc->save();

            $id=$doc->claim_id;
            $nm=$doc->file_name;
            $dc=options::where('claim_id', $id)
                    ->get();
                    $ed=$dc[0][$nm];
            dd($dc[0]->$ed);  //this dd returns "Doc2"
            $dc->$ed=''; i want it to update the content of the table column with the column with 
  name of the dd value
            $dc->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

[image: Image of the Database]

pls i really need help with this

Comment: What's problem now? Can you explain little more?

Comment: the problem is that it does not update the second table

Comment: i want it to go to table options and get column with the name of the name that is returned by $ed=$dc[0][$nm]; and sets its value to empty

Comment: Check this out if you know how to use Eloquent Model:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999557/how-to-update-a-related-model-in-laravel-eloquent

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist.    that is the error i get when i try to update

Comment: are there many `options` has same `claim_id` ?

Comment: nope, just one claim_id, no repetition

Comment: if you only one record, use `first()`, if there are many records, use `where('claim_id', $id)->update([])`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a logic error itself. If you want to update the data, use `first()` instead of `get()`, it will return the initial value. May be like this:

```
 public function docadd(Request $request){
     $doc= new documents();
     $doc->claim_id=request('id');
     $doc->file_name=request('new');
     $doc->cat=request('new');
     $doc->type='needed';
     $doc->description='needed';
    $doc->save();
        //$id=$doc->claim_id;
        $nm=$doc->file_name;
        $dc=options::where('claim_id', $doc->claim_id)
         ->first();
        //Also you can use like this 
        //$dc= options::findOrFail($doc->claim_id);
        $dc->$ed=''
        $dc->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Then you can do something if I understand you right.

Comment: $ed is not declared, i previously declared mine as $ed=$dc[0][$nm];

Comment: I thinks you can't do like: `$dc->$ed=''`, do like this `$dc->ed="someting or variable also"``. I just showed you the way.

Comment: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setAttribute(), 1 passed in C:\Users\G_BEN\Desktop\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php on line 615 and exactly 2 expected        that's what i get when i run the code

Comment: public function docadd(Request $request){
     $doc= new documents();
     $doc->claim_id=request('id');
     $doc->file_name=request('new');
     $doc->cat=request('new');
     $doc->type='needed';
     $doc->description='needed';
    $doc->save();
        //$id=$doc->claim_id;
        $nm=$doc->file_name;
        $dc=options::where('claim_id', $doc->claim_id)
         ->first();
        //Also you can use like this 
        //$dc= options::findOrFail($doc->claim_id);
         $ed=$dc[0][$nm];
        $dc->$ed='';
        $dc->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}